# Zookeeper install not working on windows 10

Tags: apache-kafka, windows-10, apache-zookeeper

Well I have my JAVA_HOME set correctly. And I am getting this error now.

```
C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin>call "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9"\bin\java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin\..\logs" "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE" "-Dzookeeper.log.file=zookeeper-User-server-HUNTER-PC.log" "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=cmd /c taskkill /pid %%p /t /f" -cp "C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin\..\build\classes;C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin\..\build\lib\*;C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin\..\*;C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin\..\lib\*;C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin\..\conf" org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg" start
2017-09-29 10:44:10,183 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
2017-09-29 10:44:10,183 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2017-09-29 10:44:10,183 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2017-09-29 10:44:10,183 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@122] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2017-09-29 10:44:10,183 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ManagedUtil@46] - Log4j found with jmx enabled.
2017-09-29 10:44:10,330 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@64] - Invalid arguments, exiting abnormally
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerConfig.parse(ServerConfig.java:61)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:101)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:62)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:125)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:79)
2017-09-29 10:44:10,330 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@65] - Usage: ZooKeeperServerMain configfile | port datadir [ticktime] [maxcnxns]
Usage: ZooKeeperServerMain configfile | port datadir [ticktime] [maxcnxns]

C:\projects\zookeeper\zk\bin>endlocal
```

Here is my config file: zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=c:/projects/zookeeper/zk/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

I have changed the dataDir repeatedly to C:/tmp to /usr/
and making sure the directories are actually there. I am at a loss. I am running this on windows 10. I have the newest JDK 9 installed and the path is accurate.

Comment: Do you have setup your ZOOKEEPER_HOME variable ? Then try this cmd in your terminal : zkserver

Comment: Also try without c: like this -> /projects/zookeeper/zk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I figured out my own answer. Everything was installed correctly. But even running from Administrator mode command prompt, zookeeper was not working. I have to actually right click on the zkServer.cmd in the bin folder and say run as Administrator. I have had this issue before with SigWebTablet software. I think its an issue with running Windows10 developer. Others around the office have this issue with Windows. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you've renamed the *conf\zoo_sample.cfg* file to *conf\zoo.cfg* and set the *dataDir* property correctly, which you've done already; use the following command to start the Zookeeper server

```
C:\zookeeper-3.4.12\bin>.\zkServer.cmd
```

Not the following

```
C:\zookeeper-3.4.12\bin>.\zkServer.cmd start
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, running as Administrator didn't work. I needed a way to tell Zookeeper to setup three instances according to the 3 config files. What did work, was to edit the `zkServer.cmd` file and remove the `"%ZOOCFG%"`parameter from the line that begins wil `call`. Now I can run `bin\zkServer.cmd conf\zoo.cfg`, `bin\zkServer.cmd conf\zoo2.cfg`, and `bin\zkServer.cmd conf\zoo3.cfg` in three command prompt windows and get my cluster up and running :)